# Reducing fourth order ode to 1st order ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

$d^4z/dx^4 -\Omega^2d/dx[(1/2)(1-x^2)dz/dx]+\lambda^2z = 0$

Given this equation, I was able to reduce the equation but was suggested not to ignore the product/chain rule. While I tried to review all the possible ad, it's not as hard as an equation that is given here. My final answer came out to be

$ Z4' = \Omega^2[(1/2)*(1-x^2)Z3' + (1/2-x)Z2']+\lambda^2Z1$, but this is not right. where should chain rule apply? Please help!

Comment: Please do not link to images, as search engines like Google and Approach0 cannot read them, but instead type up the contents.  If you need help, we have [a guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to using MathJax to format your equations nicely.

Comment: If $Ω$ is a constant, you could also set $z_4=z_3'-(Ω^2/2)(1−x^2)z_1$, so that $z_4'=-λ^2z_1$, $z_3'=z_4+(Ω^2/2)(1−x^2)z_1$, $z_2'=z_3$, $z_1'=z_2$.